# How should I pass an ssh password using a gitlab ci-cd variable for my ansible-playbook?

Tags: git, ansible, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I would like to practice automation with ansible and a ci-cd pipeline and my only problem is that I'm not sure how to reference the password for the user. If possible I would like to avoid using passwords in my inventory.yml since it would be visible in my Gitlab project.
I'm testing out the CI_CD enviroment variables so I can reference them easier.

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add ansible -v
    - apk add sshpass -v
    - ls -lah
    - mkdir /etc/ansible/
    - touch /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
    - touch ~/.ansible.cfg
    - echo "[defaults]" >> /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
    - echo "host_key_checking = False" >> /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
    - echo "[defaults]" >> ~/.ansible.cfg
    - echo "host_key_checking = False" >> ~/.ansible.cfg
    - ansible-playbook ansible_roles.yml -i inventory.yml --extra-vars=$CONTABO_PASSWORD
```

my inventory.yml file:

```
all:
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        Contabo:
          ansible_ssh_port: xxx
          ansible_host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
          ansible_password: $CONTABO_PASSWORD
      vars:
        became: yes
        become_method: sudo
        ansible_user: test
```

What should I change in the code?

Comment: Based on your above pseudo code, since `$CONTABO_PASSWORD` seems to be in your environment on the controller, you can totally drop the `--extra-vars` (which contained typos anyway) and modify the line in your inventory `ansible_password: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'CONTABO_PASSWORD') }}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ansible-vault** to encrypt your file inventory.yml using a password or a password file.

Create a file that contains your Vault password ***vault_pass.txt***

Encrypt your inventory.yml file using the ansible-vault command with the --vault-password-file option:

> ansible-vault encrypt inventory.yml --vault-password-file=/path/to/vault_pass.txt

Push your encrypted inventory.yml file into yout project Gitlab.

To run a playbook that uses the encrypted file just add the following:

> ansible-playbook ansible_roles.yml -i inventory.yml --vault-password-file=/path/to/vaultkeyfile

Or you can do the same with --ask-vault-pass which ask you for the password when executing the playbook:

> ansible-playbook ansible_roles.yml -i inventory.yml --ask-vault-pass

And finaly if you want to decrypt it:

> ansible-vault decrypt inventory.yml --vault-password-file=/path/to/vault_pass.txt